# bash: git pull works only if it is last command

Tags: linux, bash, git, sh

platform: Raspberry Pi 3 B

Please help me with this, git pull works only if it is last command, but I need it earlier. This is weird to me and I didn't find any solution

---

### working

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
git pull
```

sh script.sh gives:

```
Hello World
Already up-to-date.
```

---

### not working

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
git pull
echo Hello World
```

sh script.sh gives:

```
Hello World
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.


Did you mean this?
    pull
Hello World
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env`? Doesn't ring any bell. perhaps `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @eftshift0 with `#!/bin/bash` the behavior is the same

Comment: what does `file script.sh` say?

Comment: @eftshift0 `$ file script.sh
script.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file has the wrong EOL format (CRLF). CRLF is the format that comes from text files that are written on windows application. *NIX uses LF as EOL separator so your interpreter is getting a strange character (CR) as part of the content of every line and it's being passed onto git as part of the command you are calling... that's why it's breaking. Run `dos2unix script.sh` to convert it so that it can be read correctly.

Comment: now works ok, thank you :-) 


The file was written in Windows, i know they have different `\n` but didn't suspect this today

Comment: Looks like this was answered about the time I was typing mine. I'll go with this one because it also has a solution/fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason other than perhaps your script has un-closed quotes or special characters. In fact going by the error message, it is treating `Hello World` as a git command.

It is like you are saying:

```
[vturlapati:~] $ git Hello World
git: 'Hello' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
    reflog
[vturlapati:~] $ git 'Hello World'
git: 'Hello World' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Can you double check for special characters? If you are using vim, you could do that by executing `:set list`